# Como criar um branch limpo sem levar o histórico do master branch?

Tags: git, github

Preciso criar um branch limpo que não reflita os commits do branch master. Este branch será utilizado para disponibilizar informações sobre o projeto no Github através do [gh-pages](https://pages.github.com/) e jamais será utilizado para fazer merge com o master branch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primeiro crie um branch orfão:

```
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
```

Agora remova todos os arquivos deste branch:

```
git rm -rf .
git clean -fdx
```

Adicione algum arquivo, por exemplo `README.md`:

```
touch README.md
git add .
git commit "chore(app): initial commit"
```

Agora basta fazer o push para o servidor:

```
git push origin gh-pages
```

Faça um checkout para o master e veja os branchs existentes:

```
git checkout master
git branch
```

Este recursos é muito util para branches que tem como propósito
 documentação ou preview do projeto.